# Listar los values seleccionados en un array en PHP, AngularJS y MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

Quiero listar los datos en una `checkbox` habilitando el `select` a traves de AngularJS y PHP.

Les dejo los códigos:

**app.js:**

```
    $scope.getPhase0 = function(){
    var dataSend = {
      "service": "getPhase0",
      "token": token
    };
    Connect.post(service_api,dataSend,function(data){
      $scope.phase0 = data;
      $scope.producto = data[0].phase0_name;
      $scope.fecha = data[0].phase0_date;
      $scope.descripcion = data[0].phase0_descripcion;
      $scope.chile = data[0].phase0_chile;
      $scope.peru = data[0].phase0_peru;
      $scope.bolivia = data[0].phase0_bolivia;
      $scope.colombia = data[0].phase0_colombia;
      $scope.ecuador = data[0].phase0_ecuador;
      $scope.paraguay = data[0].phase0_paraguay;
      $scope.otros = data[0].phase0_otros;
      $scope.total = data[0].phase0_total;
      $scope.internacional = data[0].phase0_internacionales;
      $scope.nacional = data[0].phase0_nacionales;
      $scope.innovacion = data[0].phase0_innovacion;
      $scope.aplicacion = data[0].phase0_aplicacion;
      $scope.caracteristica = data[0].phase0_caracteristica;
      $scope.proliferacion = data[0].phase0_proliferacion;
      $scope.presentado = data[0].phase0_presentado;
      $scope.gerente = data[0].phase0_gerente;
      var especies = data[0].phase0_especies;
      var arrespecies[] = especies.split(',');
      console.log("Phase0", arrespecies);
      $("input[name='especies[]']").each(function(index, item){
    for($i=0; $i<$scope.arrespecies.length;$i++){
      if(item.value==$scope.arrespecies[$i]){
        $("input[name='especies[]']").attr('checked', true);
      }
    }
  })
    });
  }
})
```

**phase_0.html:**

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <label>Especies destino</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="especies[]" value="1" type="checkbox">
                                    Especie 1
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="especies[]" value="2" type="checkbox">
                                    Especie 2
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="especies[]" value="3"  type="checkbox">
                                    Especie 3
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="especies[]" value="4" type="checkbox">
                                    Especie 4
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="especies[]" value="5" type="checkbox">
                                    Especie 5
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="especies[]" value="6"  type="checkbox">
                                    Especie 6
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="especies[]" value="7" type="checkbox">
                                    Especie 7
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="especies[]" value="8" type="checkbox">
                                    Especie 8
                                </label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="especies[]" value="9"  type="checkbox">
                                    Especie 9
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**services.php:**

```
function getPhase0($mysqli){
    $ret = [];
    $query_comment = "SELECT phase0.* FROM ".$GLOBALS['base_table'].".phase0";
    if($phase0 = $mysqli->query($query_comment)) {
        $ret = $phase0->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    };
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Roberto, tienes que explicarte mejor sobre lo que quieres. Edita la pregunta y dinos con mas detalles lo que quieres.

Comment: Roberto, ¿tienes algún ejemplo de lo que has intentado hasta ahora? ¿Hay algo que no funciona como lo esperas? ¿Qué tipo de ayuda necesitas exactamente?

Answer (score 0):

Para que no tengas que hacer todas esas asignaciones en el AJAX, creo que sería recomendable que lo que devuelvas sea un JSON. 
De esta forma podrías tirar directamente de Data en el scope, con los datos totalmente formados como array.
El código será más mantenible y si tienes que añadir nuevas entradas bastaría con modificar services.php sin necesidad de tocar el javascript.